# Azure mobile service - console.log() not working in script

Tags: c#, node.js, logging, azure-mobile-services

I use Azure, subscription BizSpark. I created a Azure mobile service. I have a table TmpData. I use on the server Node.js. That script is used to update:

```
function update(item, user, request) 
{
     console.log("hello");
     request.execute();
}
```

I update the data in the TmpData but in the log nothing is added. I tried - console.warm, console.error, console.info - in the log nothing is added. I tried it and for adding data (insert script)- in the log nothing is added. Data in the table changes. Maybe I need to enable logging in the service settings? But there is no such settings azure mobile service.  How to solve this problem?

Comment: There is nothing special you have to do to enable logging, it "should" work for you.  If that simple log statement isn't showing up in your Logging area, you should contact support as it's possible there is an issue with your Mobile Service (not your script).

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem and solved by using another logging module for Nodejs. Take a look at [this](http://estynedwards.com/blog/2013/12/12/better-logging-in-azure-mobile-services/).

Answer (score 0):

Console.log() is working. When  update the data, I did not use the mobile service. I just updated the data in the script but it does not work. Thank you all.